# Customize product photo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

So I am working on a project where the client offers custom trading cards. The problem I am having is being able to overlay the card template in a way that allows the user to upload a photo that appears in a specific box.

I have tried iframe methods, I have tried using 2 divs and overlaying by using the z-index, and I have purchased 2 product customizer options but neither accomplishes what I am trying to do.

Here is a very basic image of what I need:

[Concept Example Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OFHT.png)

Comment: Applying the image as a background image. Have you tried that?

Comment: Post your code you have so far

Comment: I thought about doing that but I need the image area to update as the user edits/crops/moves the photo.

Comment: @LGSon right now I am basically at ground level. Literally I just have the container to hold this portion of the site. Everything I have tried previously I wiped out because it wasn't functioning as intended.

Comment: @AndroidDev - it would certainly help if you ask an actual question. Certainly, you may think that your exact query is clear and obvious, this is often not the case with new members. Furthermore, it would aid those trying to help you, if you articulated _why_ the other methods were no good. Without that, what's to stop someone putting in work and effort only to suggest a method you've already deemed unworthy, yet not given them sufficient information to have worked by themselves before creating/posting it?

Answer (score 0):

Just example, on simple code

[JSFIDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2c9euxso/)

NOW, if you can post your full code, we can help you further.

```
<div class="one">
Template area
</div>
<div class="two">
Template area
</div>
<div class="three">
Template area
</div>

CSS:
.one{
  position:relative
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background:url('http://pokit.org/get/img/20c0eb36b19b3006b310f5834a9f818f.jpg') NO-REPEAT;
}

.two{
  width:250px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:blue;
  position:absolute;

}
.three{
  margin-top:20px;
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background:url('http://pokit.org/get/img/b90d68274639145e23102320e602afaa.jpg') no-repeat;
}
```